# Why is Zero not falsy in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, conditional-statements

So, in weakly-typed C, 0 is evaluated as false in a boolean context (like a conditional expression) and everything else is truthy. Modern dynamic languages seem to split on whether or not zero is falsy: Python, PHP, and Javascript say yes while Ruby, Lua, Clojure, and Racket say no.

Question is, why? I googled for my question title and found [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2266083) thread on hacker news which had interesting stuff but not the answer to my question. Substituting 'lisp' for Clojure in my search yielded no historical reference.

So to be more precise in formulating my question: is there an actual technical advantage to zero evaluating as true in a conditional expression, or did it just become a quasi-standard in dynamic languages (that weren't as influenced by C) courtesy of the early lisps? Its definitely a bit odd to a programmer used to C/Python/Javascript.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The main reason is because many Clojure functions want to be able to easily tell "nothing" apart from "something". `nil` is the absence of a value, but the number 0 has a real value. An empty list is also a real thing, it's a sequence that could (for example) be `conj`ed. (Though since Clojure allows you to `(conj nil 1)` that's perhaps not the best example.)

But the key distinction is that 0 is not "nothing", it's "something". Only "nothing" (and Boolean `false`) are going to be falsey in Clojure. It's a different way of thinking about falseness, and it can be jarring when you're coming from a Python background (as I did too), but I've actually found it more useful than Python's falsey mechanics.

Comment: That's a sensible explanation. I guess I'm still caught in the mental mapping of 0 and 1 to transistor states and binary truth tables.

Comment: I'd prefer that nothing would give nothing in boolean logic, same as NULL in SQL.

Answer (score 4):

One common idiom that pierce many languages is that language need something to represent nothing. `C` is one of the low-level of high-level languages that works with pointers directly, so it seems logical to make as `nothing` the impossible address, which is 0. So 0 pointer means `nothing`. And address can be considered (and actually it is) as a number. In Java there is `null` and in Clojure there is `nil` to represent nothing.

Question from the other side is: Should we consider `something` and `nothing` as `bool` values? In C, originally, there was no `bool` type, so they had to consider nothing as `false` (actually maybe in reverse: there is `something` and `nothing` so we don't need boolean type). In Clojure there is a `boolean` type and it differs from `nil`, but the simple rule of thumb works like this: "`Nothing` and `false`" coerce to `FALSE` and other to `TRUE`. So 0 is `TRUE` in Clojure. This was done, mostly to `lisp` original ideology, and, perhaps because time show that it is common case when you don't want to work with nothing, so you just check it.

Comment: rmunn beat you to it, nevertheless +1 for the bit about C pointers and the 0 address.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the answer is both yes and no, as far as I see it, the only advantage to having zero evaluated as a non-false value is to reserve that "special" trait to Null (or None).

In Python, for instance, not only `0` and `None` are false - but also an empty list (`[]`) and an empty string (`''`). This allows a very readable code (most of the time), but has the down-side of having to do some specific testing if you want to override any of this.